# File migration via dropbox APi

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the dropbox API to migrate a large amount of files from one dropbox account to another. This seems to be taking between 2 and 7 seconds per file. Are there any ways to speed up the time it takes to move files using the dropbox API?

```
source = dropbox.Dropbox('connectionstring')
target = dropbox.Dropbox('connectionstring')

list_folder = source.files_list_folder('')
while list_folder:
    files = re.findall(r'name=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', str(list_folder))
    for f in files:
        source.files_download_to_file(f,'')
        files = open(f,mode='rb')
        target.files_upload(files.read(),'')
        files.close()
        os.remove(f)
    list_folder = source.files_list_folder_continue(list_folder.cursor)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy files or folders between accounts directly, without downloading and re-uploading the files, by using "copy references". These are strings that identify content in one account, and can be used to copy that content to another account.

To get copy references to files or folders from the source account, use /2/files/copy_reference/get:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-copy_reference-get

To use those copy references to save the files or folders in the target account, use /2/files/copy_reference/save:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-copy_reference-save

Alternatively, if you can't use copy references for some reason, be sure to check out [the Data Ingress Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/data-ingress-guide) for information on how to more efficiently upload files.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'm running into a no_permission error when trying to save the copy referenceusing target.files_copy_reference_save(source.files_copy_reference_get(f).copy_reference,''). I'm unclear on where to enable these permissions. How do I link the source and target accounts to enable correct saving of the copy reference?

Comment: @dsclough You don't need to explicitly enable anything for this. You do need to make sure the access tokens for the source and target were both created using the same app though. Otherwise, you can get that error. Make sure you're using access tokens for the same app. (It's probably easiest to just retrieve new ones to be sure.) Otherwise, open a ticket here with details so we can help investigate: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: Thanks Greg, we got it 100% this time.